# Why can't I use an apply function in R to load .rda files into the R workspace?

Tags: r, raster, sapply, rda

I have a list of .rda (RData) files. I would like to quickly load this data into R, without having to call the `load` function multiple times. I thought of using the `load()` function with `sapply`. However, using the following code, does not load any R objects in the workspace:

```
# List files    
gewataPath <- list.files(path = file.path(datdir), pattern = glob2rx('Gewata*.rda'), full.names = T)
# Load files
sapply(gewataPath, function(file) {load(file)})
```

Neither does it give any error.

Running a loop does load the .rda files into the R workspace as RasterLayer objects:

```
for (i in 1:length(gewataPath)) {
  load(gewataPath[i])
}
```

My question is: Why can't I use an `apply()` function to quickly load .rda files into the R workspace, and do I have to use a loop?

*About the data*: The data contains RasterLayers (from the Landsat satellite), located in Gewata, Ethiopia.

Comment: Did you try with a `lapply()` instead of `sapply()' ? "s" is for simplify, but there is no obvious simplification with your layers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`load()` will load the data into the environment in which it was called. When you create function to pass to `sapply`, that function gets it's own environment. If you want the objects to exist after the `sapply`, you want to load the objects into the global environment, not the function environment. You can do that with the `envir=` parameter

```
sapply(gewataPath, function(file) {load(file, envir=globalenv())})
```

Or just

```
sapply(gewataPath, load, envir=globalenv())
```